# How do I get a .cs file to understand the Click button event from my XAML file?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button, events

This is the error I get: : 'Failed to create a 'Click' from the text 'OkClick'.' Line number '5' and line position '27'.

The cs file and xaml file cannot be created on the same IDE,
so I am calling it like this.

```
 private Button okButton;

        FileStream fs1 = new FileStream(System.IO.Path.Combine(path, FileMode.Open);
        
        System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate{
        window = new Window();
        Page page = new Page();
            
        page = (Page)XamlReader.Load(fs1);
 
        okButton = LogicalTreeHelper.FindLogicalNode(page, "OkClick") as Button;                 
        window.Content = page;
        window.ShowDialog();
```

here is the event listener:

```
    private void OkClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)      
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Button in doc clicked");
        window.Close();
    }
```

and here is the XAML file that I'm using

```
        <Page   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
   <StackPanel>

 <Button Click="OkClick" Content="Ok" IsDefault="true" />       
</StackPanel>
</Page>
```

The Xaml loads properly, but nothing happens when I click the button.

Comment: I don't think OkClick is a logical node

Comment: See the non-accepted answer to the original question. Your XAML should be `<Button x:Name="okButton" .../>`, the code behind `okButton = (Button)LogicalTreeHelper.FindLogicalNode(page, "okButton"); okButton.Click += OnClick;`

Comment: I tried that, but I get the  Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Did you try `page.FindName("okButton")`?